# Bad render alert solution?

Tags: monitoring

Any party know of a product which will alert if a website renders bad - different than alert if the website is down.

If the http service is operating and the rendered output includes keywords such as "error" then i would like a notification. this is different than if the http service is not available.

for scenarios if consultant makes changes and the website is producing an error or not rendering as expected.

Bad render = Any error or missing closing tags, or accepts user defined keywords or regex.

This service is intended to assist a party in the role of customer who would not be participating in the backend alert notifications an IT admin may receive from their web server  etc.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what your websites doing, if its actually giving a error response code, a 500 error code for example, then you can make a request to the site and see what you get back.

If however its giving a normal 200 Ok response code, but is displaying an error on screen, then your pretty limited to screen scraping and getting the HTML content from the page and parsing it for error messages.

Your best bet would be to get your web server to monitor and tell you when you are displaying error pages.

Comment: "If however its giving a normal 400 Ok response code".

 Normal code is 200

Comment: Indeed it is, shouldn't write these things late at night!

Answer (score 0):

We do this with [Tembria Server Monitor](http://www.tembria.com/products/servermonitor/index.html). On its http monitor, there is a checkbox for "Perform an advanced content check" which lets you write a script to check against. It provides a default script that contains:

```
   if (ContentToCheck.indexOf("</body>")==-1)
    {
        Result.Status="Failure";
        Result.Text="An opening body tag was found but a matching closing tag is missing.";
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have used Freshwater SiteScope for this purpose for years.  They have recently been aquired by HP [(the HP page)](https://h10078.www1.hp.com/cda/hpms/display/main/hpms_content.jsp?zn=bto&cp=1-11-15-25%5E849_4000_100__) and I don't know much about it after this point.

We were using it to watch for specific words to be present when the page rendered correctly, thereby letting us know that we hadn't been hacked, and that the services were running correctly.

Comment: Sitescope works for us too.

Answer (score 0):

Nagios (GPL'ed) + check_http plugin will do most of this (up to alerting if the page contains a regex of your choosing).

But it won't validate the html in a general way, if that's what you're looking for.  You'd have to script that check yourself.